# Is there a captureVisibleTab alternative for Packaged Apps?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a Packaged App for Chrome (not a Legacy Packaged App) and need to get an image of the whole window which will then be further processed.

Unfortunately for that kind of apps it's not possible to request the "tabs" permission which is required to use `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab`. Is there an alternative way of doing that?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it now in the API, although I have reported this in [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143866)

In the meantime, you might want to try the workarounds described in this Eric Bidelman's [HTML5Rocks post](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/streaming/screenshare/). I'm not sure if these options play well with CSP restrictions, though.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a hosted app? If it is not one, and is a packaged app the "tabs" permission should be allowed.

Comment: Hi mate! You should put this in comment and not in an answer.

Comment: Is it not an answer? Well I kind of would have done that if I could. I just gained the commenting ability today!

Comment: It is a packaged app but the new ones (not the regular ones currently available in the Web Store) can't request the "tabs" permission anymore.